# Applying a class to an element according to the state of a different element in a directive template

Tags: html, css, angularjs, dom

I am trying to build a directive that uses a label and a text input field.

I want the label to show only if the input field is in focus or the field is not empty.
This is the code I have now. I need to turn it into a directive in order to use it in other fields.

```
<label class="text-field-top-label"></label>
<input  type="email"
        name="email"
        ng-model="user.email"
        ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
        required
        placeholder="Email address"/>
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to do it since I can't look for the label or the text field and I don't want to assign them IDs since I want to turn these elements into a directive.
Any Ideas will be welcome

Comment: Where is you directive code? couldn't you just use `ngBlur` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) and `ngFocus` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus)?

Comment: Why not use `ng-show="myFunction()"` in your label?

Comment: the problem with ng-show/ng-focus is that I don't have access to the input field from the label or vice versa. I can't traverse the dom elements in order to get to them like I would do if this wasn't a directive.

Comment: if I use the ngModel then it will only update on blur and only if it is valid (that is a UX demand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is how I solved this:
I used a combination of CSS and angular.
I set the display of the label to none and then I used the following CSS:

```
&:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
&:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 4-18 */
&:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 19+ */
&:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */
&:focus + label {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<input  type="email"
        name="email"
        ng-model="user.email"
        ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
        required
        placeholder="Email address"/>
<label class="text-field-top-label"></label>
```

this bit of code removes the placeholder and shows the label on focus. I am positioning the label so that it will appear above the text input.

The second requirement was for the label to show if the field has a value and I did it by querying the model. I am testing that the field exists, that it has a value !== '' and that it doesn't have errors other than "required".
The reason I am testing for errors is that the model won't have a value if it doesn't pass the validations.